# AbstractItemModel to QML Route

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtlocation

I have a set of `QPointF` in `MarkerModel` which subclasses from `AbstractListModel`. Each such marker have a status, depending on which they are colored. I want to draw all these markers on the map along with a polyline that connects all the points that have a specific status. And I will update the model from C++ side. This is my QML

```
Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(22.5726, 88.3639)
    zoomLevel: 14

    MapItemView {
        model: markerModel
        // delegate: markerDelegate // markerDelegate works
        delegate: routeDelegate // routeDelegate does not work
    }

    Component {
        id: markerDelegate

        MapQuickItem{
            anchorPoint: Qt.point(2.5, 2.5)
            coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(position.x, position.y)
            zoomLevel: 0
            sourceItem: Rectangle{
                width:  settings.marker_size;
                height: settings.marker_size;
                radius: settings.marker_size/2;
                color:  settings.marker_colors[status]
                border.color: "white"
                border.width: 1
            }
        }
    }
    Component{
        id: routeDelegate

        MapRoute{
            route: markerModel
            line.color: "blue"
            line.width: 5
            smooth: true
            opacity: 0.8
        }
    }
}
```

I actually want both, the points and the polyline on the scene. However as I don't know how to put both of them in the scene I was first trying to show the points from the model using `markerDelegate`, which worked. Now I want to view these points as a polyline with `routeDelegate`. But it complains

> Unable to assign MarkerModel to QDeclarativeGeoRoute

Answer (score 0):

If you source MapRoute from a RouteModel through a MapItemView, you always assign *routeData* to route. *routeData* is the [**role**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-routemodel.html) that RouteModel exposes, to let you access the Route elements.

Now, for your specific case, it seems that MapRoute is unsuitable.
The best approach seems to me to have 2 separate models: one exposing one js array per row, that you assign to the path property of a MapPolyline delegate, and one exposing one QGeoCoordinate per row (so many more rows), that you will use with a MapCircle or a MapQuickItem delegate

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, `markerModel` is actually subclass of `AbstractListModel`. I don't know how to create a `RouteModel` in QT (C++)

Comment: Ok, sorry, i got confused from the example, maybe you can fix it keeping only the delegate that you use?

In any case if you want to use a MapRoute with a model that is not a RouteModel, you have to have to define a role in your model through which you provide Route objects (QDeclarativeGeoRoute).

Edit: actually, now that i read your question again, you cant use QPointF to create a MapRoute or a MapPolyline. You first have to convert them to QGeoCoordinates.

Comment: How can I create QDeclarativeGeoRoute objects from C++ ? Where is that class ?

Comment: in QML that's a "Route". Then again, filling a Route by hand is not really a use case. Considering that you aren't doing routing, but you are sourcing your data from a model, you should considering using a MapPolyline

Comment: I am solving it by MapPolyline, but how can I create a QGeoRoute from C++ side and let it be used in QML ?

Comment: Do you need a QGeoRoute? QGeoRoute is supposed to be an object containing directions, maneuvers, and everything else that would be necessary to do navigation. Is your item a route for which you have all this? If not, the answer is, don't do it, as you simply need a list of coordinates.
If yes, otoh, the probably only way is by implementing a plugin that does routing.