# AbstractListModel rows added but QML View not being updated

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtlocation

I have a model that have a list of `MarkerItem` (which is a struct).

```
struct MarkerItem{
    enum marker_state{
        marker_observation = 0,
        marker_important,
        marker_redundant,
        marker_deleted
    };
    MarkerItem(const QPointF& pos, marker_state state, const QDateTime& when, const QString& label);

    const QPointF& position() const;
    QGeoCoordinate coordinate() const;
    const QString& label() const;
    marker_state state() const;

    void change_state(marker_state state);

  private:
    QPointF      _position;
    marker_state _state;
    QString      _label;
    QDateTime    _when;
};
class MarkerModel : public QAbstractListModel{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QGeoRoute* route READ route NOTIFY routeChanged)
  public:
    enum MarkerRoles {
        PositionRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        StateRole,
        LabelRole
    };
    explicit MarkerModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
  public:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
  private:
    QList<MarkerItem*> _markers;
  public:
    void addMarker(MarkerItem* marker);
  public:
    QGeoRoute* route() const;
  signals:
    void routeChanged();
};

void MarkerModel::addMarker(MarkerItem *marker){
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    _markers.push_back(marker);
    qWarning() << rowCount();
    endInsertRows();
}
```

In my QML I have

```
Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(22.5726, 88.3639)
    zoomLevel: 14

    MapItemView {
        model: markerModel
        delegate: markerDelegate
    }

    Component {
        id: markerDelegate

        MapQuickItem{
            anchorPoint: Qt.point(2.5, 2.5)
            coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(position.x, position.y)
            zoomLevel: 0
            sourceItem: Rectangle{
                width:  settings.marker_size;
                height: settings.marker_size;
                radius: settings.marker_size/2;
                color:  settings.marker_colors[status]
                border.color: "white"
                border.width: 1
            }
        }
    }
    Component{
        id: polyline

        MapPolyline {
            line.color: black
            line.width: 2
            path: []
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing this model to QML view

```
_model->addMarker(new MarkerItem(QPointF(22.5868f, 88.4149f), MarkerItem::marker_observation, QDateTime::currentDateTime(), "1"));
_model->addMarker(new MarkerItem(QPointF(22.5391f, 88.3958f), MarkerItem::marker_observation, QDateTime::currentDateTime(), "2"));

qRegisterMetaType<MarkerModel*>("MarkerModel");
QWidget* container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(_view, this);
container->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
_view->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("markerModel", _model);
_view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///main.qml"));

QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
setLayout(layout);

layout->addWidget(container);

_root = _view->rootObject();
```

The first two points that are added before setting the model to QML context appears in the view. However when I am adding some new points (based on user input from **Toolbar Action**) with  the `addMarker` function It adds the markers in the model, but view does not update

All the codes in the project is uploaded on the [gist](https://gist.github.com/neel/55b3acebbbff6d883e5fa55f581c5d47)

Comment: what is MarkerItem?

Comment: It is a very simple struct, updated code with MarkerItem

Comment: Your code should be reproducible, but if you use new types and do not show us how you define it will not be possible to execute it.

Comment: I understand that it is simple, but if you show it we save the time to create it. :P

Comment: Yes I have added `MarkerItem` in the question, Please check the question again

Comment: If you do not want to show your complete code because your question would be filled with an excessive code, I recommend you upload it to github or similar and share the links to just have to download and run it .

Comment: There are many undefined things about your code that already made me lazy.

Comment: Okay I will try

Comment: Great, let me know when you've shared it :P

Comment: Uploaded all codes to gist https://gist.github.com/neel/55b3acebbbff6d883e5fa55f581c5d47

Comment: That did not work

Comment: Check my answer. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be said that it is in your code or is in your data, what happens is that the data you are giving back is in the geographic coordinates.

If you want to keep your data you only have to change the following:

```
coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(position.y, position.x)
```

If you do not want to change your code, exchange the coordinates in your data.

I chose the first option and moving the map a bit I got the following:

[image]

Comment: Can you check my other question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017163/abstractitemmodel-to-qml-route

Comment: One more question, If I want to do something after all points in my model is rendered I need something on `onCompleated` ? I have added `Component.onCompleted: {
                        console.log(1221)
                    }` on  `Rectangle` as well as on `MapQuickItem` But nothing happened